# Import metadata in HTML files

Tags: html, import, metadata

Is there a (simple) way to import meta data from another file in HTML?

I have tens of pages with the same header. When I add or update a link or metadata, I don't want to update every file.

After reading [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file), I tried: `<link rel="import" href="/html/content.html">`. It works fine for `<link href=` or `<link rel=`, but `meta` are not imported.

Meanwhile, I created a PHP function that echoes the headers in each page, but I would have prefer a pure HTML solution.

Answer (score 0):

After the HTML file is imported you must inject its content in the main file.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function inject( import ) {
            document.head.appendChild( import )
        }
    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="/html/content.html" onload="inject(this.import)">
</head>
```

Alternatly, you can also put the script part in the imported file, since it's interpreted as soon as it is loaded.

Example in the *content.html* file:

```
<template>
    <script src="link1.js"></script>
    <meta name="author" value="someone">        
    ...
</template>
<script>
    var template = document.currentScript.querySelector( 'template' )
    document.head.appendChild( template.cloneNode( true ) )
</script>
```

*Note:* It's better to put all the content in a `<template>`, this way the content will be remain unactivated until it is inserted in the main document.